# Dynamically importing a React Hook

Tags: typescript, next.js, local-storage, lazy-loading, server-side-rendering

I have a hook in which I use LocalStorage, which means I need to make sure that window is loaded completely and this will cause issues with Next SSR.

```
const useLocalStorage = <T>(key: string, initialValue: T | (() => T)) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const jsonValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (jsonValue == null) {
        if (jsonValue === "function") {
          return (initialValue as () => T)();
        } else {
          return initialValue;
        }
      } else {
        return JSON.parse(jsonValue);
      }
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [value, key]);

  return [value, setValue] as [T, typeof setValue];
};

export default useLocalStorage;
```

So I've imported this hook dynamically like this:

```
const useLocalStorage = await import('../hooks/useLocalStorage').default
```

I've got this error in respone:

> Property 'default' does not exist on type 'Promise<typeof import("e:/Tutorial's/Front-End/React-Typescript/react_query/hooks/useLocalStorage")>'.ts(2339)
> _app.tsx(8, 66): Did you forget to use 'await'?

Can any body help me with this?
Thanks

I've also tried to use Next dynamic importing but that didn't work either, and even when I remove the default compiler says that the hook isnt callable

> This expression is not callable.   Type 'typeof
> import("e:/Tutorial's/Front-End/React-Typescript/react_query/hooks/useLocalStorage")'
> has no call signatures.

Comment: You are using the localStorage hook why don't you just import it normally ? did you try with `import useLocalStorage from '../hooks/useLocalStorage'` ? if you check their documentation how the useLocalStorage hooks work there is no need to import "dynamically"